# Multiple SAQL queries in Apex cause You have uncommitted work pending

Tags: apex, einstein-analytics, saql

I am trying to use SAQL queries in Apex and trying to execute following logic in my developer console. It gives me uncommitted work pending error which we basically get during a DML before a callout. This is the SAQL code given my analytics team and I am supposed to execute the same thing in apex. How to perform multiple SAQL queries in the same transaction and finally cogroup query,query2 to get the output is what I am trying to figure out. How to go about this solution.

```
String query = 'q = load "0Fb19000000BFX1CAO/0Fc19000000OwqcCAC";q = filter q by call_direction == "outbound";q = filter q by call_date_Week not in ["53","52"];';
  query = query+'q = filter q by date(call_date_Year, call_date_Month, call_date_Day) in [dateRange([2018,11,1],[2020,1,31])];';
  query = query+'q = group q by (call_date_Year, call_date_Month, call_date_Day);q = foreach q generate call_date_Year, call_date_Month, call_date_Day, sum(total_mou) as mou;';
  query = query+'q = fill q by (dateCols=(call_date_Year, call_date_Month, call_date_Day, "Y-M-D"));';
  query = query+'q = timeseries q generate mou as mou_proj with (length=7, predictionInterval=95, dateCols=(call_date_Year, call_date_Month, call_date_Day, "Y-M-D"));';
  query = query+'q = foreach q generate call_date_Year + "~~~" + call_date_Month + "~~~" + call_date_Day as cldmy, call_date_Year, call_date_Month,call_date_Day,mou,mou_proj,(mou - mou_proj) as variance,case when mou_proj_low_95 <= 0 then 0 else mou_proj_low_95 end as mouprojlow_95,mou_proj_high_95';
  ConnectApi.LiteralJson queryresult =  ConnectApi.Wave.executeQuery(query);
  String response = queryresult.json;
  system.debug('at 4 '+response);

  string query2 = 'r = load "0Fb19000000BFX1CAO/0Fc19000000OwqcCAC";';
  query2 = query2+'filter r by call_direction == "outbound";';
  query2 = query2+'filter r by date(call_date_Year, call_date_Month, call_date_Day) in [dateRange([2018,11,1],[2020,12,31])];';
  query2 = query2+'group r by (call_date_Year, call_date_Month, call_date_Day,"voice.account.Global_Account_Number_Displayed__c");';
  query2 = query2+'r = foreach r generate call_date_Year + "~~~" + call_date_Month + "~~~" + call_date_Day as cldmy, call_date_Year,call_date_Month,call_date_Day,sum(total_mou) as mou;';
  query2 = query2+'r = fill r by (dateCols=(call_date_Year, call_date_Month, call_date_Day, "Y-M-D"));';
  ConnectApi.LiteralJson queryresult1 =  ConnectApi.Wave.executeQuery(query2);
  String response1 = queryresult1.json;
  system.debug('at 19 '+response1);

  string query3= 'out = cogroup query2 by ("call_date_Year", "call_date_Month", "call_date_Day") left,query("call_date_Year", "call_date_Month", "call_date_Day");';
  query3 = query3+'out = foreach out generate qcall_date_Year + "~~~" + query2.call_date_Month + "~~~" + query2.call_date_Day as cldmy, coalesce(sum(query2["mou"]),sum(query[mou])) as minutes, sum(query["mou_proj"]) as projection, sum(query["mou_proj_low_95"]) as projection_low, sum(query["mou_proj_high_95"]) as projection_high,case when sum(query2["mou"]) > sum(q[mou_proj_high_95]) then 1 when sum(r["mou"]) < sum(query[mou_proj_low_95]) then 1 else 0 end as out_of_bounds;';
  query3 = query3+'out = filter out by date_diff("day", toDate("cldmy","yyyy~~~MM~~~dd"), now()) <= 90;';                                                                                                 
  ConnectApi.LiteralJson queryresult1 =  ConnectApi.Wave.executeQuery(query3);
```

Comment: Which of the `ConnectApi.Wave.executeQuery` calls generates the error? And are you absolutely sure there is no DML before these calls?

Answer (score 0):

I have never called SAQL through Apex... However what jumps to my eye is the missing/wrong stream identifier in query3

```
out = foreach out generate qcall_date_Year [...]
```

My guess is, that instead of qcall_date_Year you mean query2.call_date_Year like the following date parts in that query.

Hope that helps already.